# How to set a custom font inside an iBook widget?

Tags: widget, font-face, ibooks

I am creating an iBook and I have a widget inside this iBook.

I'd like the widget to use a custom font, hence I've added inside the .WDGT folder a myfont/ folder containing myfont.ttf.

I call it from the widget main.html using CSS, which works perfectly fine when testing on Safari on the desktop. It fails in the iPhone. Am I missing some step? Do I have to somehow tell the iPad via a plist entry to look up in the folder?

Relevant CSS code:

```
 @font-face {
     font-family: kheldarfont;
      src: url('kheldarfont/kheldarfont.ttf');
  }

 #scorebox{
    font: xx-large "kheldarfont";
 }
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Dashboard Widget, I would use:

In *Info.plist*

```
<key>Fonts</key>
<array>
<string>kheldarfont</string> 
 </array>
```

But unhappily, according to [Apple's support:](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5068)

```
Fonts   iBooks Author widgets cannot use bundled fonts.
```